# Limit of $\mathbf{tan}^2(\theta)[1-\mathbf{sin}(\theta)]$

Tags: limits

Evaulate the limit of $\mathbf{tan}^2(\theta)[1-\mathbf{sin}(\theta)]$.

> $$\lim \limits_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \mathbf{tan}^2(\theta)[1-\mathbf{sin}(\theta)] $$

I have attempted the problem by direct substitution and get:

$$\mathbf{tan}^2(\frac{\pi}2)[1-\mathbf{sin}(\frac{\pi}2)] $$
$$\infty^2 \cdot [0]$$
$$\infty \cdot 0$$
I do not know whether to state that it is zero, but I graphed it and got $\frac{1}{2}$.  The limit has to be evaluated algebraically.

Comment: seems like others have done the job mostly, I will just notice that $\tan^2 x = \frac{\sin^2 x }{cos^2 x } = \frac{\sin^2 x }{1-\sin^2 x} = \frac{\sin^2 x}{(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)}$

Comment: @Alex Thanks for another way to do the problem. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \tan } ^{ 2 }(\theta )[1-{ \sin }(\theta )]=\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \tan } ^{ 2 }(\theta )\frac { 1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ (\theta ) }  }{ 1+{ \sin }(\theta ) } =\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \tan } ^{ 2 }(\theta )\frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ (\theta ) }  }{ 1+{ \sin }(\theta ) } =\\ =\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ (\theta ) }  }{ 1+{ \sin }(\theta ) }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $$
Another way is to apply L'hospital's rule 
$$\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \tan } ^{ 2 }(\theta )\left[ 1-\sin { \left( \theta  \right)  }  \right] =\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { 1-\sin { \left( \theta  \right)  }  }{ \cot ^{ 2 }{ \left( \theta  \right)  }  }  } =\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \frac { -\cos { \left( \theta  \right)  }  }{ 2\cot { \left( \theta  \right) \left( -\frac { 1 }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \left( \theta  \right)  }  }  \right)  }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ 2 } $$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Multiply and divide by $1+\sin\theta$ and simplify.

Comment: Touché good sir.

Answer (score 4):

If you make a substitution: $\sin\theta = \dfrac{x}{1}$ then $\tan\theta =\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

[image]

As $\theta \to \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\sin\theta = x\to 1$.

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi/2} \tan^2(\theta)[1-\sin\theta] \ =\  \lim_{x\to 1} \ \dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}[1-x]$$

$$= \lim_{x\to 1} \ \dfrac{x^2}{(1-x)(1+x)}[1-x] \ = \  \lim_{x\to 1} \ \dfrac{x^2}{(1+x)} = \dfrac{1^2}{1+1} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

I know this is now what was intended for this exercise, but I thought it would be helpful.

When making substitutions like these you do need to be careful. I chose $\sin\theta$ because it is continuous at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (\tan^2\theta) (1-\sin\theta)$$

$$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\dfrac {\sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2{\theta}} \right) (1-\sin\theta)$$

$$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \left(\dfrac {\sin^2 \theta}{1-\sin^2 \theta} \right) (1-\sin\theta)$$

$$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac {\sin^2 \theta}{(1-\sin \theta)(1+\sin \theta)}  (1-\sin\theta)$$

$$\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac {\sin^2 \theta}{1+\sin \theta}  $$

Direct substitution now yields $\dfrac 12$.

Answer (score 2):

*Another way to do it.*

Just as @zhw. answered 
$$\lim _{ \theta \to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  }{ \tan } ^{ 2 }(\theta )[1-{ \sin }(\theta )]=\lim_{t\to 0}\, \cot^2(t)(1-\cos (t))$$ Now, use Taylor series built around $t=0$ $$\cos(t)=1-\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ $$1-\cos(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ $$\cot(t)=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{t}{3}-\frac{t^3}{45}+O\left(t^4\right)$$ $$\cot^2(t)=\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{t^2}{15}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ $$\cot^2(t)(1-\cos (t))=\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+O\left(t^4\right) \right)\left(\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{t^2}{15}+O\left(t^3\right) \right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t^2}{3}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Just for fun, plot on the same graph functions $f(t)=\cot^2(t)(1-\cos (t))$ and $g(t)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t^2}{3}$ for $-1 \leq t \leq 1$; you will be surprised to notice how close they are to eachother. Suppose now that you need to solve for $t$ equation $f(t)=\frac 14$. Using $g(t)$ as an approximation will give $t=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\approx \pm 0.866$ while the exact solution (much more difficult to obtain) would be $t=\pm \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{8} \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right)\right) \approx \pm 0.876$.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $\theta = \pi/2-t,$ we are looking at

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\, \tan^2(\pi/2-t)(1-\sin(\pi/2-t)) = \lim_{t\to 0}\, \cot^2(t)(1-\cos t).$$

This is the same as

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\,\cos^2t\cdot\frac{t^2}{\sin^2 t}\cdot\frac{1-\cos t}{t^2} = 1\cdot 1^2\cdot (1/2) = 1/2.$$